# PHP Thread Direction

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am looking for a starting point to get a threading project started.  I have a need on my server to take a starting WEB page, and based on the results, possibly parse out up to 20 additional pages.  My intention would be to parse these pages concurrently.

We are using CodeIgniter on the server, but not finding a ton of direction on threads.  I can grab each page one at a time, but really want to implement a queue where I can get X pages back at a time, similar to an NSOperation in objective C, or  ThreadManager in C#.

So, really just looking for a starting point.  Repeated searches are coming up dry.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you aware that PHP does not support threading?

Comment: I see many discussions that it is either thread-safe or not, so was thinking there is some way to implement.  How do folks do anything that requires concurrent processing?

Comment: They let the thing run in a web server, which spawns a process (or thread) for each request.  There's no need for concurrent processing over the course of an HTTP request.  PHP's niche is web stuff, and threading in web stuff is just plain excessive.

Comment: So, based on the above, is it possible to have multiple HTTP requests going at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for on this, the curl_multi set of calls allows for concurrent calls on a PHP server.